# ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "...ound-position: "Something went wrong" error

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a project on digital ocean's ububtu droplet. As soon as I try to install a template, I get `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

If I look in my error logs, I see

```
I, [2016-07-30T23:49:55.921388 #9319]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 73.160.138.220 at 2016-07-30 23:49:55 -0400
I, [2016-07-30T23:49:55.961647 #9319]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
I, [2016-07-30T23:49:55.983520 #9319]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
I, [2016-07-30T23:49:56.628915 #9319]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 667ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2016-07-30T23:49:56.631911 #9319] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "...ound-position: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "[headerposition];"):
    11:   <title>Christopher G. Mendla - Personal and Professional Site</title>
    12:   
    13:  <!-- From ruby begin --> 
    14:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    15: 
    16:  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    17:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1821054907133950454_37150040'
```

I had the site loaded on Digital ocean before with this template. I seem to rememebr that there was a problem with lines 14 and 16 above and I had to do something different but I can't remember what.

The portion of application.html.erb with the stylesheet tags is

```
<!-- From ruby begin --> 
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

 <!-- From end begin --> 


 <!-- The following is added to connect the template to ruby --> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "style" %>                        <!-- From template   -->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "style.ie7" %>                    <!-- From template   -->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "style.responsive" %>             <!-- From template   -->
  <%= javascript_include_tag "script.js" %>                 <!-- From template   -->
<!--  < %= javascript_include_tag "jquery.are-you-sure" %>    -->   <!-- Dirty form checker   -->


  <%= javascript_include_tag 'defaults' %>


  <%= csrf_meta_tags %> <!--  cross-site request forgery protection parameter   -->
```

I did do `rake assets:clobber` and `rake assets:precompile`

assets.rb has

```
  Rails.application.config.assets.compile = true                                    #for Production
  Rails.application. config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']      #for Production
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif]        #for Production
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(script.js)
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(script.responsive.js)
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( style.css )
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( style.responsive.css )
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( style.ie7.css )
```

If I change application.html.erb to simply be `<%= yield %>` then the site shows up without an error. I can't figure out where the error message is pointing in my css

I do see lines such as the following in style.css but I can't figure out which, if any of those lines is causing the problem

```
ul.art-vmenu ul a:hover:after
{
   background-position: center ;
}
ul.art-vmenu ul a.active:hover:after
{
   background-position: center ;
}
ul.art-vmenu ul a.active:after
{
   background-position: bottom ;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the space between the last property and the ;

For example: background-position: center;

Other recommendation, make a debug line by line in your applicacion.html.erb. Of course will take you more time, but you will know exactly the file, then concentrate in the code of that file.

Comment: The error says you've mentioned `background-position: headerposition;` in your css somewhere. Is that the case? I think that's not a valid position. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: @Chris you can use online  http://csslint.net/ for checking css error

Comment: SOLVED - I was only looking in style.css. I did a search of the whole project for background-position and found the problem was a background-position line in style.ie7. When I changed that line, the problem was resolved. My mistake was assuming that the problem was in style.css and not looking at the other stylesheets.